# Field to select an existing page

Tags: custom-fields, plugin

Does anyone know of a custom field that will allow the user to select an existing page from the site?

Throughout the site are going to be little snippets of information that will link through to another page on the site, so all I need to do is store the snippet and the link. I could just get the user to paste in the link, but I'm looking for something nicer.

I know Wygwam and the like have plugins for their linking, but I'm after something standalone.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Darren

Comment: You might want to clarify this; EE doesn't natively have the concept of a 'page'. Are you looking for a fieldtype that lets you select existing _entries_? Or select a template group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where Structure is really helpful. Once you define your pages based on Structure, you can use the StructureFrame fieldtype to select pages and get a link to their valid page URL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to build links to entries and would like to allow the end user to simply "choose" the page, I'd recommend using the native Relationship field. If your "pages" entries are housed in multiple channels then use Playa instead (with single select mode). You can easily build links to Channel entries using either of these fieldtypes.

Or, if you *are* using Structure, then as Mark said StructureFrame works great for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

**Template & Snippet Select**
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-snippet-select

Comment: No, the field needs to link to existing content not decide where the item should be displayed.

Comment: from the docs: "It allows you to select a template from within your publish field for embedding into the template." So it allows you to link to a template/page.

Comment: Yes a template, but I want to link to a specific piece of content, not a template.

Comment: if your content is stored in a channel entry, you can use playa: http://pixelandtonic.com/playa   if the content is stored in a template or snippet use the add-on I linked to above.  EE doesn't really work with "pages" so it al depends of where your content is stored.